# Apply DISTINT on the JOIN table is not working

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

My query is summing the fee based on woks table (which is 3 parts) the result should be 13000 but I am getting 39000.

```
# Order table

-------------------------------------------
| Id  | order              | Name | Fee   |
-------------------------------------------
|   1 | SELECT STATEMENT   |  ab  | 13000 | 
-------------------------------------------

# Work table
-----------------------------
| Id  | user id  | order id | 
-----------------------------
|  1  |    123   |    1     | 
|  2  |    123   |    1     | 
|  3  |    123   |    1     | 
-----------------------------


# Query 
SELECT o.order_id, SUM(o.fee) AS total_words
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN works AS wr ON wr.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN orders AS o ON o.order_id = wr.order_id
    WHERE u.id = 123

# Output =>     
Array
(
     [order_id] => 1
     [fee] => 39000
)
```

I have tried DISTINCT and group by but I get the same result.

Comment: Your table alias are messed up. What table is the alias `a` used for ?

Comment: Cheers @SameerMirji it's `user` as `u`

Comment: Your `works` table's data is tripling your results since (user_id, order_id) is not unique. `GROUP BY` would only help you if you were grouping on `work.id`

Comment: @Uueerdo That's right. is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Remove the redundant rows from `work`; or join to a subquery that gets the unique combinations from `work` rather than directly to the `work` table. Unless something you've not included in the question links to the `work` table's `id` field, I see no reason for those duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcfea/1)**

```
SELECT `user_id`, SUM(orders.`Fee`)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id`, `order_id`
      FROM works
     ) as user_work
JOIN orders
   ON user_work.`order_id` = orders.`Id`
WHERE user_work.user_id = 123
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| user_id | SUM(orders.`Fee`) |
|---------|-------------------|
|     123 |             13000 |
```

Comment: Cheers mate and that's how you do it